# 404 "Page Not Found" page for Stack Exchange API docs can be improved

Tags: feature-request, design, api, 404-not-found

For the API docs page, the **Page not found** is displaying but it **is not aligned correctly.**

For an example: [`https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/:`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/:)

[<sup>(Click for larger image)</sup>

  [image: API Docs 404 not aligned]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnIuw.png)

So can the **Page not found** page for the Stack Exchange API docs be improved?

Comment: You're accessing a JSON API, not a web page.  It's doing exactly what it's supposed to do.